# Customise the 500 Error page in php

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I have my website code in codeigniter wherein I am fusing images using Imagick in php.There are a lot of functions which can generate the `500 HTTP error`.I require a customised 500 error page that I create instead of the general browser 500 error page.

I have read that using the `ErrorDocument 500 error_doc/500.html` in `.htaccess` won't help as the Apache has handed of to PHP. But I also need a general solution pan-website which should automatically check for 500 and display the required custon page.

Comment: If those HTTP 500 errors are caused by PHP errors, I would recommend you actually *fix* or prevent them instead of making a customized error page. I *can't* believe there will be some PHP functions doing `header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error")`.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get you. Although I have fixed the error but I am adding this as a fallback option.

Comment: @BhumiSinghal, a 500 error means that ***something is wrong*** with the script. You should *never* release a site that has a possibility of generating a 500 to the public, because that means you don't handle your errors (though, if you server explodes or something, *that* would probably 500s. But it's *far* more likely your server wouldnt be connected to the internet at that point...)

Comment: I have fixed the current error but we are adding a 500 fall back just for the sakes of it. The issue remains : How to get custom 500 error page for php error.

Comment: If you do not have a solution then do not downvote. Do not just ask me to solve the current issue which is solved.

Comment: it makes sense to have a 500 error page.  shit can go wrong runtime, devs may not be able to handle everything.  what do you display to the user then?

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter actually has a custom 500 error page. If you find your getting a generic 500 error page, it could be Apache overriding the codeiginter 500 error page.

You could override it in the .htaccess to direct it to your own custom 500.html, but then you will miss out on any of the error information provided by codeiginter:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/500.html
```

You could also edit the codeiginter 500 error page found in `/application/errors/`. I think it is the `error_php.php` file.

Comment: Call as in ??? Will I have to be aware that where the 500 error may arise ? Of just adding this statement means that for that page the 500 error if ever occurs will be handled on its own?

Comment: Sorry, I left that in to make you aware of the Exceptions class, I guess it was confusing the issue. I have removed it and left just the answer.

Comment: Not Working! i have added this to the .htaccess and also created the correct html file

Comment: I guess we could have this custom file anywhere also not spcefically in application/error

Comment: I would use the .htaccess fix as a last resort. Did not editing the existing error files in the `application/error/` folder work?

Comment: Did not editing the existing error files in the application/error/ folder work? How will editing the existing files help me ? What edits should be made?

Comment: See what i require is that whenever a 500 HTTP error occurs, some code automatically runs to display the custom message. Not that I need to look at the specific function which might send the 500 and then handle it using try-catch or something.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `500.shtml` and upload it to public_html or whatever your root uploading directory is. Use the 500.shtml file to create a 500 Internal Server Error custom page.