# Getting browser 500 error message instead of codeigniter's custom page

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, imagick

My code is throwing the browser's 500 HTTP error page. While I am code in codeigniter, why is not the custom 500 error page of codeigniter being rendered?

Though I can and will correct the issue at hand , but at the moment how can I get the codeigniter's error page to be displayed???

I have also tried ErrorDocument but that is not working.

**EDIT**

Actually, its imagick that throws the fatal error.Would Codeigniter not intercept this and display its own 500 error message?

Comment: are you using XML-RPC or similar functions by any chance? CI is unable to handle some 500 errors from the actual XMl-RPC functions, they will always return 500 in my experience...

Comment: Its actually imagick that is causing a Fatal error and thus a 500. So will codeigniter never handle this Fatal error its way ?

Comment: maybe try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14702848/467164) and see how it goes ;)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter - this question is also my question and remains unsolved. :(

Comment: lol, I didn't realize that, sry :D

Comment: @ZathrusWriter its ohk! I guess the issue is that Imagick internally sends the  500 HTTP error headers to the browser and Codeigniter never really gets the chance to execute its own piece of code.